# Telerik & Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, telerik

On my project, i'm using RadScheduler.

In result of the needs, i had to create a custom edit "window".

Basically in the main page i have:

```
<telerik:RadScheduler runat="server" ID="radScheduler" SelectedView="TimelineView"
                EnableExactTimeRendering="True" DayStartTime="00:00:00" DayEndTime="23:59:59"
                DataKeyField="ID" DataSubjectField="Subject" DataStartField="Start" DataEndField="End"
                DataRecurrenceField="RecurrenceRule" DataRecurrenceParentKeyField="RecurrenceParentId"
                AllowInsert="false" AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="false" ColumnWidth="100px"
                OnAppointmentCreated="radScheduler_AppointmentCreated" AdvancedForm-Modal="true"
                Width="100%" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" ShowHoursColumn="False" Skin="Telerik" ShowsConfirmationWindowOnDelete="False"
                OnFormCreated="radScheduler_FormCreated">
                <TimelineView UserSelectable="true" GroupingDirection="Vertical" NumberOfSlots="24"
                    ColumnHeaderDateFormat="HH:mm" ShowInsertArea="false" StartTime="00:00:00" SlotDuration="01:00:00"
                    GroupBy="Room" />
                <DayView UserSelectable="false" />
                <MonthView UserSelectable="false" />
                <WeekView UserSelectable="false" />
                <AdvancedEditTemplate>
                    <scheduler:AdvancedForm runat="server" ID="AdvancedInsertForm1" Mode="Edit"/>
                </AdvancedEditTemplate>
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
```

and also a RadAjaxManager.

`<scheduler:AdvancedForm>` points to AdvancedForm.ascx

In AdvancedForm.ascx i have this javascript block

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart; // global

    /*
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph
     */
    function requestData() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.getJSON('exampleurl', function (data) {

            //Clear the "old" series
            while (chart.series.length > 0) {
                chart.series[0].remove(true);
            }

            //declare Json
            var jsonObj = {
                series: []
            };

            //Cycle through each JSONobjcect returned by the url
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var key = item['tag'];
                var value = item['data']['Velocity'];

                jsonObj.series.push({
                    "name": key,
                    "data": value
                });
            });

            //Add each of the key:value pair to the series
            for (var i in jsonObj.series) {
                chart.addSeries(jsonObj.series[i]);
            }

            // call it again after ten seconds
            setTimeout(requestData, 10000);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Test Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Viaturas'
                },
                categories: ['']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Velocidade (Km/h)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' Km/h';
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

the problem i have is that the $(document).ready is never called...

Thanks in advance for the help..

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
$(function(){
```

Comment: Had you added an alert at the top? It looks like your code wouldn't really do anything except instantiate the chart object without seeing some additional code. Also check for JS errors.

Comment: I have. It's suppose to do exactly that, but the chart doesn't even appear... I've check, it gives no errors..

Comment: If you throw in `<script type="text/javascript">alert(here');</script>` before the script block you posted, does it alert?

Comment: No.. No matter where i put an alert it doesn't fire.

Comment: Then I'd double check to see if AdvancedForm.ascx is actually being referenced properly because that behavior would not happen if the JS was being added.

Comment: I finally solved this question... Instead of pointing to a UserControl i put all code between <AdvancedEditTemplate> tag.. 

But now i have an js error: ~

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

highchart.js line 53....